# Jsonp request with Swedish character gives null response

Tags: ajax, extjs, jsonp

I'm using jsonp to request data from a web server to my application (built in sencha). The request has a dynamic parameter called 'sokt'. Sometimes the parameter has a swedish character (å, ä, ö) and sometimes it doesn't.

As long as there's no swedish charachter the server returns the expected result: for example:
http://mywebsite.se/jsonnew.php?sokt=test&_dc=1370095960312&page=1&start=0&limit=25&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback31

But if there's a swedish character in the request, the server returns nothing. Example:

http://mywebsite.se/jsonnew.php?sokt=enastående&_dc=1370096101366&page=1&start=0&limit=25&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback39

But then if i manually url encode the request enastående to enast%E5ende I get the expected result.

So, to summarize, the problem seems to be that the request from jsonp doesn't url encode the query string, it sends the unicode string which is not accepted by the php script that formats the response (which has a utf_8-header). If this really is the reason this is not working, which I'm not sure of, how would I solve this?

EDIT with code:

This is my request:

```
          Ext.getStore('storen').setProxy({ type: 'jsonp', url: 'http://mywebsite.se/synonymer/jsonnew.php?sokt=' + param}).load()
```

And this is php script:

```
 <?php

 header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');

 include("config.php");

 $dbh = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);


 $sokt = $_GET['sokt'];

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE w1 = :sokt"); 

 $stmt->bindParam(':sokt', $sokt);

 $stmt->execute();

 $output = array();

  while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {


  $output[] = array("key" => utf8_encode($row['w2']));
  }

  $callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];

 // Create the output object.

 //start output
 if ($callback) {

 echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($output) . ');';
 } else {

 echo json_encode($output);
 }


 ?>
```

Comment: Please provide some of your code.

Comment: Sure, I just updated my question with the request and the server side php script which formats and outputs the response.

Comment: I would bet on a fail of the MySQL request. What do you get if you `var_dump($sokt);die;` just after assigning it?

Comment: I get: enast%C3%A5ende, and I need enast%E5ende for the script to work. Another clue is that if I utf8_encode the querie ($sokt) the response is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the value of `sokt` in the url of the proxy, hence the proxy want change anything. So you have to care about this yourself. There is a native method for that [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

```
Ext.getStore('storen').setProxy({ type: 'jsonp', url: 'http://mywebsite.se/synonymer/jsonnew.php?sokt=' + encodeURIComponent(param)}).load()
```

As I can see someone other already answered this but deleted his answer cause you told him this want work, so here are some additional infomation:

Now your request should be send encoded like this

```
http://mywebsite.se/jsonnew.php?sokt=enast%C3%A5ende&_dc=1370096101366&page=1&start=0&limit=25&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback39
```

**Verify that** by using your browsers developer tools. If that is so the frontend has done anything right and you will have to **check the backend**.

There you have to check if the param is URLdecoded and if not decode it

```
$sokt = urldecode($_GET['sokt']);
```

and you have to ensure that your database is really **storing all the correct** way. So use some tool like PHPMyAdmin (MySQL), ManagementStudio (MS SQL) or any query tool to see if your database behaves correct and the that the Data is stored in the correct format.

Checking all this should lead you to the error

Comment: Hey, It was really something wrong with the database, allthough unclear what it was. I ended up creating a new database and then it worked fine. No urlencoding (or decoding) was necesseray, but you gave me some energy to continue trying so you'll get my endorsement :). Thanks's

Comment: @user1009453 You're welcome ;) Happy that it helped you in some sort of way.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with utf-8, first make sure everything is configured for utf-8

1. HTML
2. PHP, file store (file encoding)
3. Web Server
4. Database Columns (Collation)
5. Database Connection (Client and Server)

If done so, you're almost close to entirely forget about troubles with äöüß (No swedish chars here ;-) ).

And obviously you don't need any utf8_en|decode functions which do not work properly anyway, see the comments on php.net to these functions.

I've recently switched from ISO-8859-1 to utf-8 and it was a hell of work, but afterwards any "char conversion" was necessary any longer at all.

So: leaveing those äöü in an URL unencoded may still lead to problems. I don't kno Ext but assume that their doing a proper UTF-8 encoding of the extraParams as json requires that!

Have you tried

```
Ext.getStore('storen').setProxy({
    type: 'jsonp'
    ,url: 'http://mywebsite.se/synonymer/jsonnew.php'
    ,extraParams: {
        sokt: encodeURIComponent(params)
    }
}).load();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have checked and I have utf8 all over the place, but the query fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `extraParams` option of the proxy instead of hardcoding it in the URL:

```
Ext.getStore('storen').setProxy({
    type: 'jsonp'
    ,url: 'http://mywebsite.se/synonymer/jsonnew.php'
    ,extraParams: {
        sokt: param
    }
}).load();
```

Or, even simple, the `params` option of the `load()` method:

```
Ext.getStore('storen').load({params: {sokt: param});
```

Comment: Thank's, but no, still nothing is returned. Like before, everything works fine when not using å,ä,ö in param, but when used it gives me nothing.

Comment: Then maybe you should manually encode your param using `encodeURIComponent` before sending it...

Comment: Sounds good, but it doesn't work. Could I maybe solve this att the server side?

Comment: Probably because on my own server, everything passes -- with or without encoding it, in the params, hardcoded in the URL, or in the browser address bar...

Comment: The strange thing is, that it does not return **anything**. I would have expect some scrambled chars (like "L�schen" instead of "Löschen") due to wrong encoding but "**nothing**" indicates a problem not related to char conversion but triggered by char conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding your param on the server side:

```
$sokt = urldecode($_GET['sokt']);
```

Try forcing your database connection to UTF8 before executing your query:

```
$dbh->prepare("SET NAMES 'utf8'")->execute();
```

Maybe one of these or the combination of both will work.

Comment: Nope, still the same problem. I found another thing though. If I put "enast%E5ende" as the param, and var_dump $sokt I get "enast�ende", ie, the browser doesn't read the code, but the mysql_query works!! But if I utf8_encdode $sokt var_dump gives me "enastående" but he query fails. I have utf_8 collation and utf_8 database connection.